# overlay-fs and editing upper directory with vim

Tags: vim, overlayfs

For developing purposes, I am using the `overlay-fs` to merge custom changes to the base file structure. The merged-folder is used by a java application.

Now I experienced a strange behavior when using *vim* for editing the custom files in the upper-folder: changes are not reflected in the merged-folder. (Apparently) Every other editor seems to work (nano, code, gedit, ...). Hence, vim is saving files different. For reproducing do the following as root:

```bsh
# created needed folders
$ mkdir -p overlay/{lower,upper,work} merged
# mount the folders with overlay-fs
$ mount -t overlay overlay -o upperdir=overlay/upper,lowerdir=overlay/lower,workdir=overlay/work merged/
# create file in lower-folder with content "foo"
$ echo "foo" >overlay/lower/file.txt
$ cat merged/file.txt
# foo
# create override for file.txt in upper folder
$ echo "bar" >overlay/upper/file.txt
$ cat overlay/lower/file.txt
# foo
$ cat overlay/upper/file.txt
# bar
$ cat merged/file.txt
# foo # <- FALSE
# remount for reinitialization
$ mount -o remount merged
$ cat merged/file.txt
# bar # <- TRUE
$ echo "baz" >merged/file.txt
$ cat overlay/lower/file.txt
# foo
$ cat overlay/upper/file.txt
# baz
$ cat merged/file.txt
# baz
```

*if the file is not already existing in the `upper`-folder the changes are not reflected to the merged-folder. one has to remount the filesystem.*

**use vim to edit merged/file.txt; modify to `foobar`;save**

```bsh
$ cat overlay/lower/file.txt
# foo
$ cat overlay/upper/file.txt
# foobar
$ cat merged/file.txt
# foobar
```

expected as well. all ok

**now use vim to edit overlay/upper/file.txt; modify to `foobaz`; save**

```bsh
$ cat overlay/lower/file.txt
# foo
$ cat overlay/upper/file.txt
# foobaz
$ cat merged/file.txt
# foobar # <- FALSE
```

*and this is unexpected. I think that `merged/file.txt` should have changed to `foobaz`as well*

```bsh
$ mount -o remount merged
$ cat merged/file.txt
# foobaz # <- TRUE
```

Doing the same change with i.e., `echo` works correct:

```bsh
$ echo "foobazaar" >overlay/upper/file.txt
$ cat overlay/lower/file.txt
# foo
$ cat overlay/upper/file.txt
# foobazaar
$ cat merged/file.txt
# foobazaar # <- TRUE
```

*instead of `echo` one can use `nano` or `code` as well*.

Can anyone give me an explanation for this behavior of vim? Is it a bug in overlay-fs?

Comment: *Changes to the underlying filesystems while part of a mounted overlay
filesystem are not allowed.  If the underlying filesystem is changed,
the behavior of the overlay is undefined*. [overlayfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt)

Comment: @meuh thanks for the document, i wasn't aware of it. So it is not a bug, nevertheless I am curious why `vim` is behaving differently